# shouldChangeCharactersInRange method not called after calling becomeFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

Hi i am new to the iOS,

i am using several text fields in my project, so i want use **becomeFirstResponder** for editing done for any one of text field. it is working fine in **xcode 3.2.5** but it makes problem in **xcode 4.2.1**

In **xcode 4.2.1** after calling the **becomeFirstResponder** i could not edit the text field, it is showing the virtual key board i could tap the keys but tapped keys are not entered in text field.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 14):

Firstly add this delegates in interface:

```
 @interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

If using from xib then right click on UITextField and bind delegate with fileowner else 
add this code in viewDidLoad's method.

```
  yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Add UITextField's delegate and it will be called

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField //resign first responder for textfield 
 {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
 }

 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 {
   return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have set the delegate but it is still not working if i remove calling the **becomeFirstResponder** it is working fine. in xcode 3.2.5 it is working fine even if calling the  **becomeFirstResponder**. problem is only in xcode 4.2.1